# How do I use a local XML file as a DataProvider for a Spark List control in Flex 4.5?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

I am building a Android app in *Flash Builder 4.5* using *Flex 4.5.1* and I am having the hardest time using a locally stored (/data/data/app-name/db/pellets) XML file as the *DataProvider* for a *Spark List control*. I've looked on the net for the past 3 days and have tried a bunch of different ways to get the code working but to no avail.

I have a *SkinnablePopUpContainer* with a *Spark List control* (list1) that I'd like to populate with the "*name*" element in my locally stored XML file (pelletdb.xml) that contains about 170 entries with 6 elements each. The XML looks like this:

```
<tin>
  <pellet>
    <caliber>0.177</caliber>
    <name>AA Field</name>
    <bc>0.0210</bc>
    <weight>8.400</weight>
    <style>N/A</style>
    <material>Lead</material>
  </pellet>
  <pellet>
    <caliber>0.177</caliber>
    <name>Beeman Bearcub</name>
    <bc>0.0110</bc>
    <weight>8.000</weight>
    <style>N/A</style>
    <material>Lead</material>
  </pellet>
</tin>
```

When I click on the list1 entry I'd like to populate some Labels. I haven't been able to get the XML data into an ArrayCollection to be used as the DataProvider for my Spark List control. I know I must be doing something wrong someplace, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting the data from the XML file and cannot convert it to ArrayCollection or you cannot read the local XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dataprovider for the List control you need an ilist datatype.
So you could do something like

```
list.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(xml.children());
```

You can see a sample on Peter Dehaans great Flex example page:
[Using an XML data provider with the Spark List control in Flex 4](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/04/using-an-xml-data-provider-with-the-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/)